# Unicode to Character Converter In PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, unicode, unicode-string

I need to convert unicode to character in PHP. I am using MySQL database to store text The text is in unicode format with collation utf8-general-ci. When I retrive those data and display, some special characters are displayed:: like "à¤®à¤¿à¤¨à¤¿à¤¸à¥à¤•à¤°à¥à¤Ÿà¤®à¤¾ à¤•à¤°à¥à¤•à¥‡ à¤¨à¤œà¤°" for the text "मिनिस्कर्टमा कर्के नजर". This is Nepali font in unicode format. I need it in character or ascii format in PHP. I have tried utf8 encode and decode but none of them worked(displays question marks ???? in decoding and "Ã Â¤Â®Ã Â¤Â¿Ã Â¤Â¨Ã Â¤Â¿Ã Â¤Â¸Ã Â¥ÂÃ Â¤Â•Ã Â¤Â°Ã Â¥ÂÃ Â¤ÂŸÃ Â¤Â®Ã Â¤Â¾ Ã Â¤Â•Ã Â¤Â°Ã Â¥ÂÃ Â¤Â•Ã Â¥Â‡ Ã Â¤Â¨Ã Â¤ÂœÃ Â¤Â°" on encoding). So, how can I get ascii value or character or unicode value of each unicode characters from mysql database in PHP???

Comment: did you tried html_entity_decode(), if not then try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I used [this](http://pageconfig.com/post/portable-utf8) php library and use utf8_chr_to_unicode_style function to convert each unicode charaters to code. I converted all the codes to my required font code(preeti nepali font code). That's all :).

Comment: Try `utf8_chr_to_hex` from the same library. This is a better and improved function in portable utf8 1.3 and if you want to convert to integer, you should use `utf8_ord()`.

Answer (score 3):

Chnage the collation to `utf_bin` and in header of your pages `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`. Hope it works.

Comment: This displays "मिनिस्कर्टमा कर्के नजर", which is the actual text in database. But I dont need it, I need its equivalent ascii or unicode value so that I can convert this text to another font.

Comment: Another font or language? @BarcelonaTsandesh

Comment: Actually I am going to map this current database font into another font which is also Nepali Font. For that, I need ascii code or character that can be converted into another font. Or language too.

Comment: There is no ASCII value for any Devenagari symbol. If you have a “visual font” (ie one where each character like `a` maps to a semantically-unrelated glyph) then you would need not just character mapping tables between the real character code and the font glyphs, but also complex text layout handling to work out which glyph matches which sequence of characters: for example `मि` is one composed glyph but two characters, ma+i. It is much better for sanity and semantics to use standard Unicode fonts wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try function [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

It's a function for conversions from different encodings. Please try some at the link provided above. If you cannot manage to figure it out then comment and I will try to research more on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

i have an issue related with the utf-8 charset. I've been all around the web (well, not entirely) but for quite awhile now and the best advice was and is to set the header charset to "UTF-8".

However, I  was developing my web application locally on my machine using xampp (and sometimes wamp so as to get a distinction of the two when it came to debugging my code). Everything was working great =). But as soon as i uploaded it online, the result was not all that jazzy (the kind of errors you would get if you had set the headers to a different charset like "iso-8859-1"). 
Every header in my code has UTF-8 as the default charset, but i still got the same "hieroglyphic thingies". Then you guys gave me the idea that the issue isn't my code but the php.ini that was running it.. Turns out my local machine was running php 5.5 and the cpanel where i had uploaded my web application was running native php 5.3. 
Well, when i changed the version of php that my cpanel was set by default from Native PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5, believe you me guys =) it worked like a charm just like as if i was right there at the localhost of machine.

**NOTE**: Please, if you got the same problem as i did, just make sure your PHP is 5.5 version.. I'm posting this coz i feel you guys. Cheers!